# Value of specific key from a dictionary using lambda?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I have a product array which looks like table below:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    name                   |  review                        | word_count                     |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                           |                                | {'and': 5, 'wipes': 1,         |
| Planetwise                |  These flannel wipes are OK,   | 'stink': 1, 'because' : 2, ... |
| Flannel Wipes             |  but in my opinion ...         |                                |
|                           |                                |                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                           |                                | {'and': 3, 'love': 1,          |
| Planetwise                |  it came early and was not     | 'it': 2, 'highly': 1, ...      |
| Wipes Pouch               |  disappointed. i love ...      |                                |
|                           |                                |                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                           |                                | {'shop': 1, 'noble': 1,        |
|                           |                                | 'is': 1, 'it': 1, 'as': ...    |
| A Tale of Baby's Days     |  Lovely book, it's bound       |                                |
|  with Peter Rabbit ...    |  tightly so you may no ...     |                                |
|                           |                                |                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Basically the `word_count` column contains a `dictionary(key : value)` of word occurrence of `review` columns sentences.

Now I want to build a new column name `and` which should contain value of `and` in `word_count` dictionary, if `and` exists as a key in the `word_count` column, then the value, if it doesn't exist as a key, then `0`.

For first 3 rows the new `and` column looks something like this:

```
+------------+
|    and     |
+------------+
|            |
| 5          |
|            |
|            |
+------------+
|            |
| 3          |
|            |
|            |
+------------+
|            |
| 0          |
|            |
|            |
+------------+
```

I wrote this code and it's working correctly:

```
def wordcount(x):
    if 'and' in x:
        return x['and']
    else:
        return 0

products['and'] = products['word_count'].apply(wordcount);
```

**My question:** Is there any way I can do this using `lambda`?

What I've done so far is:

```
products['and'] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda x : 'and' in x.keys());
```

This returns only `0` or `1` in columns. What can I add to the line above so that `products['and']` contains the value of `and` the key when it exists as a key in `products['word_count']`?

I'm using ipython notebook and graphlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Just return the value of `x['and']` if it exists, otherwise `0`.

For example:

```
data = {"word_count":[{"foo":1, "and":5}, 
                      {"foo":1}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.word_count.apply(lambda x: x['and'] if 'and' in x.keys() else 0)
```

Output:

```
0    5
1    0
Name: word_count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `products['word_count'].apply(wordcount)` does, but from the rest of your question, while you *could* do something like the following with a `lambda`:

```
products['and'] = (
    lambda p: p['and']['and'] if 'and' in p['and'] else 0)(products)
```

It's kind of ugly and awkward, so I'd would recommend using the built-in dictionary `get()` method instead because it's debugged, shorter, easier to maintain, and quicker:

```
products['and'] = products['and'].get('and', 0)
```

Your fixation on using a `lambda` reminds me of what some call the [Law of the Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument): "...it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail".